# Why is this page using the homepage template and not the one it should?

Tags: templates, redirect

---

One of my clients has installed a theme where when a visitor enters their username and email to register as a new user they get shown a link to download a custom report file.

This was working fine on my clients test installation, but now they've converted the site to a live site the download link doesn't show and instead the page uses the homepage template...

I'm stumped as to why it's happening so any advice would be great.

[Here's the test page](http://www.graphictankclients.co.uk/veredor/download-report/)

[Here's the live page](http://www.veredor.com/?page_id=140)

[Here's a jsFiddle of the PHP code](http://jsfiddle.net/k8AHK/)

Comment: The two pages look identical to me. Can you point out the difference? (And maybe clear your cache.)  And in general it is better to post the code here than to point to jsFiddle.

Comment: If you enter some dummy information into the boxes you'll see the difference. The test site shows the download link perfectly, and the live site reverts to the homepage template...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two is that the test site has pretty permalinks enabled and the live site doesn't. If you look at the URL, the issue becomes apparent, this is not a valid URL/query string:

```
http://www.veredor.com/?page_id=140?register=true
```

If you change the second `?` to an ampersand, the page renders correctly.

Either enable pretty permalinks on the live site, or modify your code with [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to correctly append the additional query argument:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'register', 'true' ); ?>" />
```

Comment: I had a feeling it might be this but my client was taking their time to give me their FTP details (They're using a Zeus server which requires a custom script to allow pretty permalinks).

Comment: Nice catch Milo.  And Dean, I feel your pain, I had a client running WP on a windows server. Can't everyone be on a LAMP stack!?